# If $H$ is a closed subgroup of a Lie Group $G$, and $p:P\to B$ a principal G-bundle. How to show that $q:P\to P/H$ is a principal $H$-bundle?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $H$ a closed subgroup of $G$. Suppose we are given a principal $G$-bundle $p:P\to B$, how to show that the quotient $q:P\to P/H$ is a principal $H$-bundle? Where $P/H$ denotes orbit space of $P$ under the right action of $H$.

I have no clue how to construct the trivialization charts.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3001718/principal-bundles-with-quotient-map, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315445/quotient-manifold-theorem-provides-a-fibration, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2859848/quotient-map-g-rightarrow-h-backslash-g-is-a-principal-fibre-bundle-how-to There are probably more...